# Floyd Warshall complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, shortest-path, asymptotic-complexity, floyd-warshall

Someone can give to me the time complexity of this procedure inside the for iteration?
This piece of code is the "reconstruction path" part of FloydWarshall algorithm.
prev[n][n] is the matrix of the nodes that are between source node and destination in the shortest path.
printAllSP runs n^2 times in the iteration, what i can't really figure out is the number of recursive calls that it does every time, only understood that depends by i value (max n), j value(max n) and the number of k (???) nodes that interject in the shortest path between i and j, by my evaluations including the for cycles this part runs in On^4 but the total algorithm complexity is On^3.Enlight me pls!

```
 void PrintAllSP(int i, int j, int prev[n][n]){
if (i == j)
    print i
else  {
    PrintAllSP(i, prev[i][j], prev);
    print j
}
}

//PSEUDOPART OF MAIN
for i = 1 TO n
    for j = 1 TO n
        PrintAllSP(i, j, prev);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `n` nodes total, which means `O(n^2)` shortest paths are printed. Each shortest path can only have up to `n` nodes in it. Therefore, only `O(n^3)` nodes can be printed. Since each base recursive step results in one node being printed, this means only `O(n^3)` base recursive steps total.